# Java Math unexpected trailing decimal

Tags: java

Currently learning Java, can anyone explain why the following code yields this output?

```
System.out.println(330*1.1);
```

363.00000000000006

When it should simply equal 363. Why is there the trailing decimal?

Alternatively, the following code correctly outputs 363.0 yet is mathematically equivalent.

```
double check = 330; 
check = check + check*0.1; 
System.out.println(check);
```

Comment: Because floating-point is an approximation.  In particular, there's no exact way to represent 1.1 in IEEE double precision.